# AngularJS / Karma Unit testing in AppEngine Python project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm experimenting with AngularJS on top of GAE/Python. I tried moving in a few bootstrap template files and I'm not getting the following errors in my Unit tests (default unit tests).

Source: 
https://github.com/m2mIO/angular-portal

```
Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
WARN [config]: "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-junit-reporter".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-junit-reporter --save-dev
WARN [proxy]: proxy "http://localhost:8080" normalized to "http://localhost:8080/"
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5)]: Connected on socket 4fu9UWsj1npbCkHr1G-4
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /Users/kyleroche/PycharmProjects/2lemetry/app/js/fullcalendar.min.js:7
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /Users/kyleroche/PycharmProjects/2lemetry/app/js/gcal.js:107
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /Users/kyleroche/PycharmProjects/2lemetry/app/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js:6
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /Users/kyleroche/PycharmProjects/2lemetry/app/js/jquery.dataTables.js:39
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /Users/kyleroche/PycharmProjects/2lemetry/app/js/jquery.flot.js:32
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.716 secs / 0 secs)
```

I'm also not exactly sure what to add to my app.yaml to serve the e2e tests. They are located in test/e2e/runner.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Used exclude for template files and had to server /test from static assets dir.